# Change Status Bar Background in Search Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

I am trying to change my Status Bar background color but I seem not to be doing it right.

Here's a Screenshot of my simulator:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, when search bar is active, the status bar background changes to white.

The idea is to use the same background color with the search controller when search controller is active.

Here is the code I used:

```
class DisplayListTVC: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
```

...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:nil)
    self.resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.73, green:0.81, blue:0.87, alpha:1.0)

    self.resultSearchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)

}
```

Comment: you should post a picture of what you mean, it's unclear if you mean "change this when the search is activated" or "change this so that it's the same always"

Comment: @Larcerax I do not have enough rep to post a picture yet. If you can, check this out http://i.stack.imgur.com/1JNdD.jpg

Comment: thats fine, so you want the color of the text to change? or you want the backgrond color to change? right now, it looks like you maybe want the text color to change since I don't see the text of the status bar.

Comment: @Larcerax I'm good with he Text color, I want the background color to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what you mean, I had the same problem. I found a solution, so you can still see the status bar. Just had this two lines of code in your function and it will look much better after ;) However I don't know how to change the color, it will be grey. Tell me what you think about it ;)

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Comment: Thanks mate @Omid. This solved my problem. And for the background color being grey. You could easily change with          `controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor()`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?:

```
self.resultSearchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

if this doesn't work, then tell me, there's other options to look at

Comment: Weird! This works on the Simulator but does not work on real device

Comment: do you have any idea why it happens that way?

Comment: you'll have to show a lot more code than you have for me to be able to help you find out what else woudl need to be done. there's too many variables and it would be a guessing game, post more code in your question, like your viewcontroller itself

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only thing i needed to do to sort this out was to go to storyboard/xib, select the ViewController with this problem and in the Attributes Inspector uncheck "Under Top Bars".

It's pretty self-explanatory... Happy coding!